# Excel as a service behind an API

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office

If I have a spreadsheet that acts as, essentially, a giant calculator, is it possible to host an Excel file on OneDrive / Sharepoint / behind a webserver and then use it remotely via an API (provide inputs, retrieve outputs) in a way that allows multiple concurrent users to separately do this at the same time?

Comment: I see that this has been marked as duplicate, but the referenced answers only deal with the case of using (something like) interop in order to control an entire reified instance of Excel on the back-end. I am well aware that Microsoft does not support his model. However, I am hoping to solicit answers which, perhaps, somehow use the Office365 suite / Graph API / some of the more modern Microsoft stuff. I think it might be possible somehow via one of these avenues, because in that case Microsoft is more in control, so they might allow it?